# Can I make tools in blender which opens as a separate window?

Tags: python, scripting

Rather than my tools attached to either sidebar or properties i want just a panel which consists of all the tools and then once i click on the name of the tool , it open separately in a different smaller window.Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as is with BPY, but there's this addon that implements it:

[Floating Windows - Coding / Released Scripts and Themes - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/floating-windows/1163493)

It works on Windows only. But you can either use it as is, or look at the code to make your own.